# How to ship luggage from Dar Es Salaam to Kenya

Tags: luggage, transportation, shipping, tanzania, kenya

I'm looking to ship three large bags from Dar Es Salaam in Tanzania to Watamu or Malindi in Kenya. If that's not possible, then to Mombasa.

It would be ideal to not spend a fortune (e.g. with a courier like DHL).  I've reached out to Tahmeed Coach buses and haven't had much luck but I hear they can do it.

Are there others that may be able to do it safely and reliably?

The other catch, is the bags would have to wait for my pickup which will be two weeks later, so they would have to be stored safely at the pickup in Malindi/Watamu or Mombasa.

Dimensions of the bags:
2 bags that are 38 x 14 x 12 inches, both weigh 30 lbs each
1 bag that is 62 x 19 x 16 inches, and weighs 50 lbs

Comment: Have you looked into freight costs on the regional airlines?  Or contacted freight forwarders in Dar?